# Type Assertion vs Importing Interface

Tags: go, interface

I'm working on a project that would require some level of abstraction on some data and I would like to keep the packages that use the data as independent as possible so I can swap things out in the future.

Here are 2 possible ways that I thought of, one is having a common data interface and have all the places import it. The other is to have each package define its own interfaces and do a type assertion.

Which is the most Go/general way of doing it?

```
// Importing interface
// src/model
type IData interface {
    myint() int
}

// src/dataextractor
import src/model
type DataExtractor struct {
    foo() IData
}

// src/service
import src/model
type ServiceDataExtractor interface {
    foo() IData
}
type Service struct {
   extractor ServiceDataExtractor
}
func (s Service) serve() {
    v = s.extractor.foo()
    // do stuff with v 
}
```

vs

```
// type assertion
// src/dataextractor
type DataExtractorData struct{}
func (d DataExtractorData) myint()int {}

type DataExtractor struct {
    foo() interface{} {
       reutrn DataExtractorData{}
    }
}

// src/service
type ServiceData interface {
    myint() int
}
type ServiceDataExtractor interface {
    foo() interface{}
}
type Service struct {
   extractor ServiceDataExtractor
}
func (s Service) serve() {
    data := s.extractor.foo()
    v, ok := data.(ServiceData)
    // do stuff with v
}
```

Comment: You don't need to import an interface to satisfy it.

Comment: @HymnsForDisco which is especially interesting considering Go prohibits import cycles. You can get situations where two packages "work with each other" without one importing the other.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simple rules to keep in mind.  An interface type should be declared in the package that **wants to receive** that interface type.  To satisfy an interface, you don't have to import it.  All you need to do is declare the methods as are specified by the interface.

When do you use interfaces?  Typically, when you have a field, or parameter, that you want to be able to accept multiple data types, and you can do all you need to do with it by calling methods.  How do you determine what goes in the interface?  You simply ask yourself: "What methods would I need to call on this value to make use of it?"

The only seemingly meaningful method in your example is `myint() int`, and the only place it seems you intend to use it is in `Service`.

```
type Service struct {
   extractor interface {
      myint() int
   }
}

func (s Service) serve() {
    s.extractor.myint()
}
```